# Is it possible to make nested query in jq with JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, jq

Here's my JSON:

```
{  
   "A":[  
      {  
         "AT":"text"
      },
      {  
         "AT":"text2"
      }
   ],
   "B":[  
      {  
         "name":"text",
         "power":10
      },
      {  
         "name":"text1",
         "power":20
      },
      {  
         "name":"text2",
         "power":40
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to have all B element with the same name as A element. So in this case the result would be `['text',10,'text2',40]`. I try this query `[.B[] | [.name , .power][]]  | map(in([.A[].AT]))`but it doesn't work it's throw me an error:

> jq: error (at :23): Cannot index string with string "A"
>       exit status 5

I don't know how to fix it but I think it's about the parent node, it doesn't recognize the nested query in the in function. So is it possible to make nested query in this language and how can handle a problem with nested query for other case like other function or other situation as pipe ?

PS: I work in JAVASCRIPT (node.js)

New problem, I have this query:
`( .Move | map({(.name): {accuracy : .url.accuracy, damage_class: .url.damage_class.name, power :  .url.power, priority: .url.priority, target: .url.target.name, type: .url.type.name, null}}) | add ) as $b | .results | select(.name=="bulba") | map(.url.moves[].move.name | [., $b[.][]]) | add`

and it's work perfectly without `select(.name=="bulba")`

> jq: error (at :158): Cannot index array with string "name"

Should I show the JSON with this ?(because is a little bigger than the previous one)
But it's start with this:

```
    {  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "name":"bulba",
         "url":{  
            "moves":[  
               {  
                  "move":{  
                     "name":"flamiche"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"sala",
         "url":{  
            "moves":[  
               {  
                  "move":{  
                     "name":"DAMSSSS"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "Move":[  
      {  
         "name":"flamiche",
         "url":{  
            "accuracy":50,
            "damage_class":{  
               "name":"physical"
            },
            "power":50,
            "priority":0,
            "target":{  
               "name":"foe"
            },
            "type":{  
               "name":"fire"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"DAMSSSS",
         "url":{  
            "accuracy":90,
            "damage_class":{  
               "name":"status"
            },
            "power":null,
            "priority":2,
            "target":{  
               "name":"self"
            },
            "type":{  
               "name":"grass"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please include a minimal and complete example of your JSON file that we can copy and paste to a local file and work on it. Your example is invalid JSON as it is now.

Comment: I directly post the simpelst version of my JSON because I don't know how to make a linkable copy paste for my JSON sorry about that

Comment: okay, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're piping `[.B[] | [.name , .power][]]`'s product --which is to be an array of **strings**-- to `map(in([.A[].AT]))`, i.e input is changed and `.A` is lost, and you're trying to get `.A[].AT` from those **strings**. This is not the only issue but the reason why you get that error. You better do something like this:

```
( .B | map({(.name): .power}) | add ) as $b
| .A | map(.AT | [., $b[.]]) | add
```

If your input is too big using `reduce` you can get better performance:

```
( reduce .B[] as $b ({}; . + ($b | {(.name): .power})) ) as $b
| reduce .A[].AT as $a ([]; . + [$a, $b[$a]])
```

---

As for your second question, by passing `results`, an array of objects, to `select(.name=="bulba")`, as the error message states you're trying to index an array with a string. To filter objects under `results` move `select` into `map` like:

```
map(select(.name == "bulba") | .url.moves[].move.name | [., $b[.][]])
```

Comment: Can you explain this portion of the code: `[., $b[.]]` please ? And can you explain how map(x) works because the manual doesn't explain any of those scheme present in your code

Comment: `.AT | [ ., $b[.] ]` is the same as `[ .AT, $b[.AT] ]`. it creates an array consisting of `.AT` and value keyed with `.AT` in `$b`.

Comment: map is defined as `def map(f): [ .[] | f ];`, it expands its input, applies filter `f` to all expanded values, and packs resulting values in an array. See [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq).

Comment: I almost FORGOT ! Actually my JSON is a bad example, it's a simplier version of my problem but not a good one because, FOR EXAMPLE, if for each B element there one more attribute [name, power, accuracy] how would you do that ? Because you can't use the trick you used for only 2 attributes...

Comment: I found a way !! Look at this `( .B | map({(.name): {power: .power, accuracy}}) | add ) as $b | .A | map(.AT | [., $b[.][]]) | add ` It work very well ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's good, you could write just `power` instead of `power: .power` though.

Comment: Is it possible to help me again because I've done a real model of my project and I don't know why it's doesn't work... I tried something, but you need to have the JSON to get how it work and I don't know if it's possible to UPDATE my topic or CREATE another topic just for that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194501/discussion-between-bosskay972-and-oguz-ismail).

Comment: Wait what ? It's work perfectly but why ? Why put select on the map ? How exactly map solved the problem ? Is it a type of cast ?

Comment: no, `select` is defined as `def select(f): if f then . else empty end;`, what's happening there is actually: `[ .results[] | if .name == "bulba" then . else empty end | .url.moves[].move.name | [ ., $b[.][] ] ]`. We're expanding `results`, filtering some objects, creating an array for each and packing them all back in an array.

Comment: But your query does `results | if .name == "bulba" ...`, and since results is an array and arrays can't have string keys, you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all `B` objects that are on `A`, you can use `Set` and `concat` to create an object with all the A values. Use `filter` to filter the object `B`

```js
var obj = {"A":[{"AT":"text"},{"AT":"text2"}],"B":[{"name":"text","power":10},{"name":"text1","power":20},{"name":"text2","power":40}]}

var allAs = new Set([].concat(...obj.A.map(o => Object.values(o))));
var result = obj.B.filter(o => allAs.has(o.name));

console.log(result);
```

You can also use `flatMap` (available on Node 11.0.0) as:

```js
var obj = {"A":[{"AT":"text"},{"AT":"text2"}],"B":[{"name":"text","power":10},{"name":"text1","power":20},{"name":"text2","power":40}]}

var allAs = new Set(obj.A.flatMap(o => Object.values(o)));
var result = obj.B.filter(o => allAs.has(o.name));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I prefer the first answer because I want to use query instead of directly use js, but thanks anyway !